# Using CrudRepository's save

Tags: java, spring, crud

Using

```
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

What is the difference between these two:

```
entity = crudRepository.save(entity)
crudRepository.save(entity)
```

Re-referencing the variable to the save()'s return value seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> entity = crudRepository.save(entity)

Allow you to get back the id generated if you save a new entity.

Comment: The object has the generated id in the second case.

Comment: The javadoc precise the purpose of the second case :  "Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely" http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-

Comment: So does the save method update some of the referenced object's properties and return a new object with additional properties? That would make no sense at all...

Answer (score 0):

The snippet `entity = crudRepository.save(entity)` is used when you want to get back the saved entity to perform further operations depending on it.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) reads:

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.